# Meteor React Subscribe to specific collection data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I am building a React - Meteor web app and I need to get access to a specific piece of data from a collection.

There are three main components, the company list, the project list and the task list.  When I list all of the companies, I can select one and then display all of the project associated with that company.  What I want to then do is click on a project and see all of the tasks which are associated with that project.  My data structure is as follows (as you can see, projects are an array of objects):

```
{
    "_id" : "aQnrkqMi6ugEvav4a",
    "owner" : "7Gp49ZCtGC9oEx3jN",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-05-08T15:52:27.777Z"),
    "data" : {
        "name" : "lkhgb",
        "contacts" : [ 
            {
            ...
            }
        ],
        "projects" : [ 
            {
                ...
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "ljhvljhvblhkjvblhkj",
                "id" : "258757206",
                "tasks" : [ 
                    "task1", 
                    "task2"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

In my TaskList Component, I'm exporting it like so:

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
    const {companyId} = props.match.params;
    Meteor.subscribe('company');
    return {project: Company.findOne(companyId)};
}, TaskList)
```

Where I'm pulling the companyId off the props.  I am also pulling off the projectId from props, but when I query the collection it's just returning undefined.  I have published the GitHub repo as live here - https://github.com/GlueDigiStu/ClientManager and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You did indeed subscribe to the "company" publication on the server.
Although that publication does not exist.

```
Meteor.publish('company', function (companyId) {
  const publications = [];
  publications.push(Company.find(
    {
      _id: companyId,
    },
  ));
  return publications;
});
```

This will publish the id you want from the server.
Then the subscription from the client would be:

```
Meteor.subscribe('company', props.companyId);
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

If I may I'll also give you some suggestions. Having documents in documents in documents isn't really great for publications.
I would suggest to place projects and tasks into new collections and only subscribe to tasks once their project is selected.

Comment: Hi Mitch, thanks for that - I've tried your initial method and I can't seem to get it working.  As for your suggestion, I think I'll go down that route and try to split my one big collection into three separate ones.  I can't quite get my head around the docs for `transform` though.  Would you have any advice on the topic?  I've found this one tutorial but it's for Iron Router, rather than React (but I guess it's similar) http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/joins-in-meteorjs-and-mongodb

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help you with the transforms and reactive joins. We never use them in our projects since they can cause huge performance drops if the subscribed collections are not carefully managed and just spit out with all there attributes. Just be carefull about what you publish with the transforms.